# My JS console says that .getTime is not a function when i use the getTime() method in JS

Tags: javascript, html, gettime

I am not able to use the .getTime() method, can someone help me? Error message in link! The original date is just from basic html date input.

JS:

```
document.getElementById("lastMenDate").addEventListener("change", function () {
    var inputMen = this.value;
    var lastMenDate = new Date(inputMen);
    console.log(lastMenDate);
});

document.getElementById("targetDate").addEventListener("change", function () {
    var inputTar = this.value;
    var targetDate = new Date(inputTar);
    console.log(targetDate);
});

document.getElementById("calc").addEventListener("click", function () {
    var timeDifference = targetDate.getTime() - lastMenDate.getTime();
    var daysDifference = timeDifference / (1000 * 24 * 60 * 60);
    console.log(daysDifference);
});
```

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rIb0D.png)

Comment: `targetDate` is only defined inside the _previous_ callback function.

Comment: Please post the code or error as text in question, not an image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as commented, your vars are not scoped to the window / "all functions", so you can just assign your variable to the window/global and reference it that way.  You could also look at creating an object which employs the calculation.

```js
document.getElementById("lastMenDate").addEventListener("change", function () {
    var inputMen = window.inputMen = this.value;
    var lastMenDate = window.lastMenDate = new Date(inputMen);
    console.log(lastMenDate);
});

document.getElementById("targetDate").addEventListener("change", function () {
    var inputTar = window.inputTar = this.value;
    var targetDate = window.targetDate = new Date(inputTar);
    console.log(targetDate);
});

document.getElementById("calc").addEventListener("click", function () {
    var timeDifference = window.timeDifference = window.targetDate.getTime() - window.lastMenDate.getTime();
    var daysDifference = window.daysDifference = timeDifference / (1000 * 24 * 60 * 60);
    console.log(daysDifference);
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I didn't realize!

Comment: You are welcome.  This may not be the best way to accomplish what you would like, but it is a nudge in the right direction based on where you are currently.  Think about creating an object with properties of "lastMenDate", "targetDate", "timeDifference" and use those to expose the calculation for "daysDifference". then you can modify your EventListeners to change that objects properties.  A basic implementation of that would prevent you from "polluting" the global scope.